# How can I disable or limit disk cache memory usage globally?

Tags: centos

The disk cache takes too much memory in my OpenVZ VPS. How can I disable or limit disk cache memory usage globally?

I am using CentOS 6.4.

Comment: Why would you want to limit the disk cache in use? What is your use case?

Comment: One relevant use case: when the VPS comes with (for example) 8 GiB "max. guaranteed RAM" and 16 GiB "max. dynamic RAM", which is only allocatable when the VPS supervisor approves. This setup can make software run out of memory when being denied "dynamic RAM", so it's meaningful to limit dynamic RAM use by tuning the cache size down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to decrease the likelihood of VFS caching, increase the VFS cache pressure by tuning the value of `/proc/sys/vm/vfs_cache_pressure` (the default is 100). This will aggressively reclaim dentries and inodes from memory. 1000 might be a good starting point. On my system a setting of 1000 reduces slab by around 75% or so.

Note that this is probably not what you want to do, however. There are very few use cases that you want to reduce filesystem cache memory usage -- it is freed for use by programs as soon as they need it.